# RGBA decimal notation to arithmetic notation

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, rgba

I have to customize a iOS app and the guideline says:

> Please don’t use RGBA values in 0 to 255 decimal notation, but use 0.0
>   to 1.0 arithmetic notation instead!

For exemple, the default app color #70C7C6 in the guideline is converted to (0.298, 0.792, 0.784, 1.000).

How can I convert other colors? I never knew this arithmetic notation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string hex values into integers, then to get the arithmetic notation divide each value by 255.

For example "C7" -> 199 -> 199/255. -> 0.78.

The last value is opacity, which sounds like in your case would always be 1.

Comment: I think it's opacity?

Answer (score 1):

A color component is a number over a specified range, while working with hex or integer values you have (usually) a number in `0-255` (represented by `0x00-0xFF` if working in hexadecimal). But you can express the same value by normalizing it in the range 0.0-1.0, you do so by dividing each component by the maximum allowed value, eg:

You have `0xC7` in hex, which is `199` in decimal, you divide it by `255.0f` and you obtain `0.780f`.

In practice `UIColor` already provides [methods](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred?language=objc) to obtain normalized values, you just need to convert a number from hex notation, which can be done easily or by using a simple [library](https://github.com/Inferis/UIColor-Hex):

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithCSS:@"70c7c6"];
CGFloat r, g, b, a;
[color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a]
```